# Row Transfer according to the person login

Tags: asp.net

I have two pages, called "Staff_Common" & "Staff_Main". Both pages have a gridview.

"Staff_Common" can be view by all staff. but "Staff_Main" is personal for each staff.

My question is, when a particular person login, how to transfer a row from "Staff_Common" gridview to "Staff_Main" gridview  if the user click on a row at "Staff_Common" according to the user which clicked it?

Comment: Populate the Staff_Main GridView separately based on their role/permissions?

Answer (score 1):

To get the data in the "Staff_Main" page according to the row clicked in "Staff_Common" page you need to somehow *pass the ID of the Staff corresponding to a row clicked in the Staff_Common page* to the Staff_Main page so it can generate the GridView accordingly.

To do that you need to set the properties:

```
AutoGenerateSelectButton="true"
DataKeyNames="id"
OnSelectedIndexChanged="StaffCommon_OnSelectedIndexChanged"
```

on the Staff_Common GridView.
DataKeyNames value must be the name of the column that stores the id.

Then in the code behind of same page store in session the ID of the item on which was clicked:

```
protected void StaffCommon_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["staffId"] = (sender as GridView).SelectedDataKey;
}
```

Now all you have to do is to bind the data in Staff_Main page accordingly to the id stored in session: Session["staffId"].